# Ruby: How to make custom DSL accept variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this class:

```
class Items
    def initialize &block
      (block.arity < 1 ?  (instance_eval &block) : block.call(self)) if block_given?
    end

    def button_id button_id=nil
      unless @button_id.present?
        raise "button_id must be supplied" if button_id.nil?
        @button_id = button_id
      end
      @button_id
    end
end
```

Now, when I do this it works:

```
Items.new do
   button_id 1
end
```

But when I do this, it fails because I think it is not on the same scope:

```
@button = Button.find(params[:button_id]
Items.new do
   button_id @button.id
end
```

How can fix this to take arguments outside the scope?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: "undefined local variable or method @button for #<Items..."

Comment: "I think it is not on the same scope" – Yes, that's the *whole point* of `instance_eval`. It changes `self` inside the block to the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Items
  def self.dsl
    new.tap do |item|
      yield item
    end
  end

  def button_id(button_id)
    @button_id = button_id
  end
end

@button = Button.find(params[:button_id])

item = Items.dsl do |item|
  item.button_id(@button.id)
end

puts item.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was to pass the arguments to the block like this:

```
Items.new do |item|
   item.button_id @button.id
end
```

Less beautiful DSL but works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right use case of DSL, when you can simply assign the attributes by arguments.

```
class Item
  attr_accessor: :button_id

  def initialize(args)
    button_id = args[:button_id]
  end
end
```

Another problem is in your usage. The instance would be of little value if you don't assign it to a variable

```
item = Item.new button_id: button_id
```